# How to mimic bash filename completion with custom list of words

Tags: bash, autocomplete

This is probably very easy to do but for some reason even after reading articles/tutorials on programmable bash autocomplete I can't get it to work properly.

I want to mimic the bash filename autocomplete but provide my own set of words (for each level)

For instance

level1: foo bar

level2: bar baz daz

```
> mycommand [TAB][TAB]
foo    bar
> mycommand foo/[TAB][TAB]
bar   baz   daz
> mycommand foo/b[TAB][TAB]
bar   baz
```

Any pointer in the right direction would be helpful (I tried splitting the current word with '/' as separator, putting it in an array and try to figure out the next set of words from there, I also tried adding '/' as a word separator in COMP_WORDBREAKS but that brings its owns set of problems)

Answer (score 0):

a shell completion is basically a complimentary script for your binary to provide a shell completion functionality. for instance, checkout [git auto-complete for bash](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash).

so depending on the designated shell, you will have to provide a script that comes a long with your program and can be executed on the designated shell to provide an auto-complete feature.